# How to set title font size in coefplot::coefplot.default()?

Tags: r, coefplot

Using the `library(coefplot)`, the following code creates a coefficient plot

```
library(dplyr)
library(coefplot)

set.seed(123)

x1 <- sample(1:8,10000,replace=TRUE)
x2 <- sample(1:6,10000,replace=TRUE)
x3 <- sample(1:7,10000,replace=TRUE)
y  <- sample(0:1,10000,replace=TRUE)

df <- as.data.frame(cbind(x1,x2,x3, y))

glm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3, family = "binomial", data = df) %>%
  coefplot::coefplot.glm(., title = "My title", xlab = "Coefficient values", ylab = NULL, intercept = FALSE)
```

I would like to change the font size of the title (`"My title"`). How do I achieve this - or does anyone have a workaround? (I have tried to specify the `cex` parameter without any effect.)